# SQL selecting on compared lists

Tags: sql, subquery

My goal here is to gather only recipes that call for ingredients a user already has in their pantry. Right now it is pulling my entire inventory of recipes I have stored in my database. Was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

**Note:** a recipe has many ingredients and is linked back to the ingredients via a separate `recipe_ingredients` table with attributes `recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id` and `recipe_ingredients.recipe_id`.

```
select distinct recipes.name
from recipe_ingredients,
    (select distinct recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id
    from pantry, recipe_ingredients
    where pantry.user_id = 1 and recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = 
pantry.ingredient_id) MATCH
where recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = MATCH.ingredient_id;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: My database is set up on Azure

Comment: You are selecting `recipes.name`, but the table `recipes` is not in the query. Try replacing `recipe_ingredients` with `recipes` in the main part of the query (not the sub-query which gives `MATCH`).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not obvious how `pantry`, for instance, relates to recipe ingredients.